# How to create JSON file from GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, convert, json

I have a GeoJson file and I want to convert it in JSON. How to do that. I have used many of online converters but did not make it.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GeoJSON is technically already in JSON format. What do you need to do with the data?

You can save GeoJSON data to a file with a `.json` extension. You can also encode the GeoJSON data to get a string just like any other JSON data.

Comment: I need to place that here: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-service-management-for-the-enterprise/page/product/facilities_service_management/reference/r_Manually-builtMaps.html    And just json is supported.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that software, but it looks like they support geojson maps. Here is a link to the documentation that they have for geojson. https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-service-management-for-the-enterprise/page/product/facilities_service_management/reference/r_GeoJSONMapFiles.html

Comment: Yes, but it is doesent work. Can you write how to encode geojson?

Comment: If you are using php, you can use `$encoded = json_encode($geojson)`. In javascript you can do `json = JSON.stringify(geojson)`. If you are using a different language, just google "how to encode json in x language".

Comment: JSON and GEOJSON are not the same.